# Show that every solution of the following differential equation has an analytic continuation along any path that avoids its singularities .

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem states as follows. Let $f(z)$ be  a meromorphic function on an open set $\Omega$. Consider a differential equation 
\begin{align}
 y''+f(z)y=0.  \hspace{1cm}(1)
\end{align}
Show that every solution of $(1)$ has an analytic continuation along any path $\gamma$ on $\Omega$, such that  $\gamma$ avoids the poles of $f(z)$.

Comment: What is the independent variable in your ODE?  Is it $z$?

Comment: Yes, it is. $f$ only depends on $z$.

Comment: See the ODE section of Cartan's *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions*.